# Plot multiple custom figures (pdf) in LaTeX

Tags: positioning, subfloats

I am trying to plot these six different images (in PDF) shown below:

[image]

But, for some reason I could not plot what I wanted. These green figures are exactly how I would like to see my figures, which are images from my result in a PDF form. Below is my code:

```
\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[ht!]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig/main.pdf}
        \caption{\small main}
        \label{}
    \end{subfigure}
%
    \begin{subfigure}[ht!]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig/1.pdf}
        \caption{\small 1}
        \label{}
    \end{subfigure}
%
    \begin{subfigure}[ht!]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig/2.pdf}
        \caption{\small 2}
        \label{}
    \end{subfigure}
     \begin{subfigure}[ht!]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig/3.pdf}
        \caption{\small 3}
        \label{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[ht!]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig/4.pdf}
        \caption{\small 4}
        \label{}
    \end{subfigure}
     \begin{subfigure}[ht!]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig/5.pdf}
        \caption{\small 5}
        \label{}
    \end{subfigure}
   \caption{\small  intervals.}
\end{figure}
```

What I am doing wrong here? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an empty line between the first and second, and between the fourth and fifth. Else, leave no empty lines.

Note also that the `subfigure` environment is not a floating environment, and the float parameters `ht!` make no sense for them. You can use optional arguments for `subfigure` as well, but they relate to the vertical alignment on the line they're placed.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig/main.pdf}
        \caption{\small main}
        \label{}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig/1.pdf}
        \caption{\small 1}
        \label{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig/2.pdf}
        \caption{\small 2}
        \label{}
    \end{subfigure}
     \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig/3.pdf}
        \caption{\small 3}
        \label{}
    \end{subfigure}

   \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig/4.pdf}
        \caption{\small 4}
        \label{}
    \end{subfigure}
     \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig/5.pdf}
        \caption{\small 5}
        \label{}
    \end{subfigure}
   \caption{\small  intervals.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score -1):

Though your problem has been solved but here is what I do in such situations which proves to be more effective, compact, time saving and coherent .... Download and install a free image manipulation program called inkscape. Right click "1.pdf" and open with inkscape. Leave the default options checked and once opened, select your figure and copy paste for 4 more times. Arrange the shapes in desired order, save the pdf and import just one image containing all the shapes instead of having to import five figures and using commands like \subfigure. I have found this method to be extremely efficient and effective. Hope it helps.

Comment: The question was: How to arrange it in **LaTeX**, not in an external program such as InkScape or InDesign or whatever ;-)